# Batch Commit for Lucene Index

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, batch-insert

I want to index the documents in batches. I am setting the `IndexWriterConfig.setMaxBufferedDocs()` to set the total number of documents in memory before they are committed back in the index.

Do I have to keep count on the document added and explicitly issue `writer.commit()` for the index to flush the documents in the memory or the writer will automatically take care of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucene will actually only flush documents to disk when the ram buffer size or the maximum buffered docs limit is reached (there is no auto-commit). To make them serchable, you will need to actually call `IndexWriter.commit` and reopen a searcher.

Answer (score 2):

Lucene does it itself, of course.